# Как сделать появление панелей по нажатию

Tags: android, android-studio

Хочу реализовать такую фичу как в FBreader. А именно: при чтении в полноэкранном режиме при нажатии на центр экрана появляются панели(бар сверху и некая рабочая область снизу). Подскажите как это реализуется. Вот скриншоты 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]    [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Скрытие/показ Toolbar при прокрутке**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`ScrollView` легко заменяется на любой прокручиваемый контейнер, будь то `RecyclerView`, `ListView`, `ViewPager`, `WebView`, `NestedScrollView`. Что используется в приложении на скриншоте, сказать не могу. Возможно какой-то кастомный `layout`, но родителем ему служит какой-нибудь из написанных выше. `CoordinatorLayout` позволяет повесить `behavior` на любой прокручиваемый `view`, который будет вместе с его прокруткой скрывать `AppBarLayout`, в котором и находится `Toolbar`.

**Скрытие/показ Toolbar при нажатии**

Я так понял экран не сожержит никаких виджетов, тоесть рабочей областью является только `Toolbar`?
Вам надо поймать момент когда пользователь нажимает именно в центр экрана? Или в любую другую область? Когда происходит касание или клик?

**Некая рабочая область снизу**

Насчет панели снизу - если желаете анимированное "выезжание" кейса снизу, то используйте `BotfomSheet`.

Comment: Можно поподробнее о том как реализовано отображение и сокрытие toolbar